# MS SQL Server 2005 - Grouping Similar Data

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find a solution to the following type of groupings:

My Data

```
Formula #   Date
1           2016-01-02 12:05:00
1           2016-01-02 12:07:00
2           2016-01-02 12:10:00
2           2016-01-02 12:15:00
3           2016-01-02 12:25:00
3           2016-01-02 12:30:00
3           2016-01-02 12:50:00
3           2016-01-02 12:55:00
2           2016-01-02 13:05:00
2           2016-01-02 13:25:00
2           2016-01-02 13:40:00
```

And I am trying to get a result like this:

```
Formula     Count  Start Date             End Date
1           2      2016-01-02 12:05:00    2016-01-02 12:07:00
2           2      2016-01-02 12:10:00    2016-01-02 12:15:00
3           4      2016-01-02 12:25:00    2016-01-02 12:55:00
2           3      2016-01-02 13:05:00    2016-01-02 13:40:00
```

I've tried various things and while I can roll up the similar formula numbers, I cannot seem to get it to sort out to get the results in the format I've listed. I'm also not sure at all how to get the starting and ending date of the groups of data..

Any thoughts or help would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

The below query will group by the formula and provide the count as well as min and max dates. Based on the data in the table there is no way to know that there are supposed to be 2 separate sets of data for Formula #2, so it is being grouped into one row.

```
SELECT
    [Formula]
    ,COUNT([Formula]) AS [COUNT]
    ,MIN([Date]) AS [MIN_DATE]
    ,MAX([Date]) AS [MAX_DATE]
FROM 
    #test_table
GROUP BY
    [Formula]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply... 

this was basically the query I came up with to begin with... but I was unable to get things to separate out and group like I described in my example. Specifically, with Formula 2 being logged in 2 separate groups... ultimately, that's what I need since what I am trying to do is provide a chronological list of formulas and date ranges for when they were run, so grouping all of Formula 2 together does not accomplish this..

Comment: If there is an indicator that specifies the start/middle/end of a formula this would be straightforward. With the data provided, the only way I can think of to accomplish that is to use a case statement on the difference between the min/max times to set a threshold on the duration of each 'formula'.